# Kotlin - Need return type String but got any instead

Tags: kotlin

I need this function to return a String so I can call it in another function but instead I got any. How can I make it return a String?

```
private fun getValue(text: String){
myMap.forEach { (k, v) -> v.find {it.key == text}?.values?.joinToString(separator = "#") ?: ""}}
```

myMap is a `Map<UUIDint, List<SomeAttribute>>`

SomeAttribute is a data class

```
data class SomeAttribute(
  var key: String = "",
  var values: List<String> = ArrayList()
)
```

I want the output String to look like this `122PR` or `122PR#374DH` respectively.

Comment: _What_ string do you want it to return? Can you show some sample inputs and outputs? Also, what type is `attribute.value`?

Comment: For which `myMap` do you want that output? In other words, how does the output relate to the input? What are you actually doing?

Comment: Could you please create a dummy `myMap` and its respective output so we can [reproduce what you want](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in our compilers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forEach` method returns `Unit`. You need to do some side-effect inside it (modify some variable defined beforehand) and return this variable. But it's better to use other methods, which will immediately return what you need.

Depending on what exactly `String` you want to get from this `Map` there are several options:

1. If you want to get `values` of first met `SomeAttribute` which has required `text` as a `key`, then you need to:

```kotlin
myMap.values.flatten().find { it.key == text }?.values?.joinToString(separator = "#")
```

2. If you want to get `values` of all first met `SomeAttribute`s in each `List<SomeAttribute>`, which have required `text` as a `key`, then you need to:

```kotlin
myMap.values.flatMap { v -> v.find { it.key == text }?.values ?: emptyList() }.joinToString(separator = "#")
```

3. If you want to get `values` of all `SomeAttribute`s which has required `text` as a `key` in each `List<SomeAttribute>`, then you need to:

```kotlin
myMap.values.flatMap { v -> v.filter { it.key == text } }.map { it.values }.joinToString(separator = "#")
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want it to return the first match it has you could do like this:

```
private fun getValue(text: String) : String {
    myMap.forEach { (_, v) -> v.find {it.key == text}?.values?.joinToString(separator = "#")?.let { return it }}
    return ""
}
```